# iOS - "UIViewController from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have an UIViewController which has UITableView in it. Everything works fine. In "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" methos I want to activate a "show" segue to UIViewController. I set it in Storyboard, created its ViewController class etc.

When I choose the cell, I get an error saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier
>   "UIViewController-ndM-tm-7SM" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

Interestingly, I found that although I put a ViewController to the storyboard, it's changing to Table View Controller by itself. It's picture:

[image]

Tis is not initial situation, at first i checked the same place and there were only ViewController. Probably this is the problem.

I looked the same question asked before but they are different. My root view controller is not table view controller, it's view controller including table view.

Anyway, what should i do to handle this? I use prepareForSegue method either and it seems that there's nothing wrong about it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you set any segue from cell to another vc ?

Comment: So you dragged and dropped an UITableView to the UIViewController right? Did you connect the tableView's delegate and dataSource to the file's owner?

Comment: @vaibhav i have set a segue from view controller to another vc. Should i make it from cell?

Comment: @GellertLee if you're asking for my root view controller, it's delegate methods works fine.

Comment: @narsimelus check my ans, yes you can connect segue using custom cell.

Comment: have deleted uitableview conncection from uitableviewcontroller by mistake in storyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

You definately can create a segue from a VC to another VC, and call it from `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`

I've tried to create a segue from the `rootViewController` (not the cell) to the `detailViewController`, it works fine.

First, make sure you have connected the dataSource and delegate in storyboard.
[image]

Then connect the segue, 
[image]

Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"show" sender:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

And this should be working.

Comment: I thought and did the same at first but resulted problem. As it brought error, i tried different things and it become complicated unnecessarily :)

Answer (score 0):

you must inherit  UITableViewController not UIViewController

write your .h file like this way

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
//your property & method add here
@end
```

Comment: user176196 it can be achieved using `UIViewController` :)